# How to config vite HMR port in Nuxt3 config?

Tags: nuxt.js, vite

I'm using Nuxt3 within a Docker compose setup where port 8001 is the accessible port for the node container running Nuxt3 channeled via an nginx reverse proxy.

My nuxt.config.ts looks like this:

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    vite: {
        server: {
            hmr: {
                clientPort: 8001,
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Somehow it seems the clientPort setting for the HMR of vite is not picked up by Nuxt3. The page is constantly reloading in the dev setup.

Any idea whether I've misconfigured this or this is not yet possible in Nuxt3?

In a similar setup with Vue this setting in the vite.config.js is working properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is caused by Vite (by default) using port `:24678` and this being blocked by Docker, causing Vite to error out and hard-reload. To fix the issue you simply need to ensure that the relevant port is exposed and accessible.

As per this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/nuxt/vite/issues/172) you can add the following to your Docker compose file (specifically to the Nuxt3 service, *not* the nginx service):

```
# Your Nuxt 3 service

  ports:
    - "24678:24678" # or in your case: - "8001:8001"
```

You may also need to add in a `vite.config.js` file to the root of your Nuxt3 folder, with the following:

```
export default {
  server: {
    hmr: {
      protocol: 'ws',
      host: '0.0.0.0',
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding a vite.config.js with these settings did not work, but opening port 24678 to the node container did work!

Comment: Man, opening port 24678 was absolute nugget! Was looking for that whole day. Thank you!

Comment: With Nuxt 3.2.3 seems to not working.. I get GET http://localhost:3010/_nuxt/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error every time. Where actualy the _nuxt folder should be? I can't find it.

Comment: Working like a charm. I used in nuxt 3.x configuration. Be aware that nuxt documentation says no all vite configuration can be used within nuxt 3.x
Maybe it will change in the future version. I don`t know

Answer (score 3):

you need to add this port beside the main port like in your docker-compose.yaml

```
ports:
  - "3000:3000"
  - "24678:24678"
```

also be sure the vite config is like

```
//nuxt.config.{js,ts}
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vite: {
    server: {
      hmr: {
        protocol: "ws",
        host: "0.0.0.0",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## Nuxt3 with Docker compose **July 2023**

- Edit **nuxt.config.ts** to allow vite to run our application

```bash
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  vite: {
    server: {
      hmr: {
        protocol: 'ws',
        host: '0.0.0.0',  
      }
    }
  }});
```

- In docker-compose.yml file, expose port **24678** which is nuxi based port like this. Default **Port 3000** for Nuxt app(Port **24678** is vite dev Server)

```bash
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 24678:24678
```

## Expose different port apart from **3000**, chose **8000**

- Edit **nuxt.config.ts** and expose port 8000

```bash
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
devServer: {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: 8000, // you can replace this port with any port
  }});
```

- In docker-compose.yml file,expose port **8000** this way.

```bash
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```