# nuxt3 vite + docker + nginx = net::err_empty_response

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, vite, nuxtjs3

I'm upgrading an open-source project with Nuxt3 and I'm having a few problems with `net::err_empty_response` showing every second
[image]

Here is my setup REDACTED as you can see I have Nginx acting as a reverse proxy, the project works and show what has to display but I don't understand how to fix that HMR error.

In `client` I've added the vite.config file and now is using port 3000 instead of a random one that it was using at the beginning but is still showing that error, I don't understand in which part of the stack I'm failing to connect as the page is shown and the API response is also present.

If I remove the client port mapping I have net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED while if I map 3000:3000 the FE reloads constantly, the same goes if I move the 3000:80 in the Nginx port section

The logic is that when you go to localhost then Nginx redirect everything to localhost:3000 while if the URI contains API to the PHP port.

I came across this https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/1021 but if I change the ports according to my setup (port 80 and using ws) the page keep reloading instead of showing that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so after a bit of digging and a different search I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72016669/how-to-config-vite-hmr-port-in-nuxt3-config) besides other resources that helped me to solve the error.

I've modified the `server` config in the nuxt.config.js like this:

```
export default {
  ...
  server: {
    hmr: {
      protocol: 'ws',
      host: '0.0.0.0',
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

and then in the docker-compose I've opened both ports for the client service:

```
  # Client container
  client:
    build:
    ....
    ports:
      - "24678:24678"
      - "3000:3000"
```

No changes were made to the Nginx config.